# Copy/Paste From Word To Expression

Tags: html, css, microsoft-expression-web

When I copy/paste from a word doc into Expressions Web, I get strange behavior.  My screenshot from word below, sometimes it will place the top line in one `<span>` tag and the rest in a separate `<span>` tag causing a slight gap between the two.  Is this becoming the new norm of how to code using HTML or do I have hidden characters/breaks in my word doc that I do not see.  For example, a straight copy/paste presents this HTML

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><u>This is the top row of my information<o:p>
</o:p></u></b></p>
<span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;
Times New Roman&quot;;mso-fareast-font-family:
&quot;Times New Roman&quot;;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;
mso-fareast-language:EN-US;
mso-bidi-language:AR-SA">This is information that should come 
up under the top 
row and I am just trying to span it for more than 1 line, 
maybe go to 2 or three 
or four or five or six.<span style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </span>
Oh here comes 
more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more.
<span style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;
</span>Oh I am not done yet, not yet not yet.
<span style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;
</span>Okay I think this is enough once I reach one more last line.
<span style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;
</span>Almost to the end, yes I hit it!</span>
```

Which to me the exact same can be achieved by simply using this syntax:

```
<p><strong><u>This is the top row of my information</u></strong><br>
This is information that should come up under the top row and I am just
trying to span it for more than 1 line, maybe go to 2 or three or four or
five or six.  Oh here comes more and more and more 
and more and more and more and more and more.  Oh I am not done yet, 
not yet not yet.  Okay I think this is enough once I reach one more last   
line. Almost to the end, yes I hit it!</p>
```

Why all of the extra syntax with Expressions?

[image: Word Screenshot]
[image: Expression Design View]
[image: Expression HTML View]

Comment: Did I answer your question? If not, feel free to comment on it so I can see if I have anything to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe that usually copy and pasting from Microsoft Word can cause issues with Expression Web. I will do some more reason as to exactly why, but when I was in college, I was specifically told that we should copy and paste from a program like Notepad if we were to do this.

According to Microsoft, it seems a straight copy/paste is not recommended. If you haven't already, try pasting with the formatting. [See here for more information.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295574.aspx)

There is also [another link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/0ef18667-7c74-4449-9a29-f91c038e7617/pasting-word-content-into-expression-web?forum=web) here to a Microsoft forum that states that Word has horrible web mark-ups because it is not a web design tool.

Comment: that is a good answer and does explain why all the extra syntax was added.  Just irritating that I then have to go back in and manually add bold/italics/bullets etc to the text.  I was hoping this product would be more like dreamweaver where I could do a straight copy/paste from any medium and get proper html code as well as display properly on the page.

Comment: Yes in my experience I found expression Web to be very finicky so if you are able to find another program that can do what you need, that would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Ya get what you pay for and since expression Web is free and Dreamweaver costs your first born...haha